# Creating a full diallel using R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, rbind

I am relativly new to R, excuse if this question is too basic.
I am wondering whether there is a good and fast way to create a full diallel using R?

I have a matrix that looks likes:

```
          M1 M2 M3
   Line1  A  B  A
   Line2  A  A  B
   Line3  B  A  A
```

From this matrix I would like to create the following data frame:

```
 X       Y       M1   M2  M3
 Line1   Line1   AA   BB  AA
 Line1   Line2   AA   BA  AB
 Line1   Line3   AB   BA  AA
 Line2   Line1   AA   AB  BA
 Line2   Line2   AA   AA  BB
 Line2   Line3   AB   AA  BA
 Line3  Line1    BA   AB  AA
 Line3  Line2    BA   AA  AB
 Line3  Line3    BB   AA  AA
```

I think this might be possible by creating a couple of nested loops and using paste to combine the A and B lettercodes. But probably there are better and more "R-like" options (using `cbind()`?).

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to think of the indices of the rows of your data that make up each line of the desired output. Using your data:

```
mat <- matrix(c("A","B","A",
                "A","A","B",
                "B","A","A"), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

I create those indices using `expand.grid()`. The first row of your output is formed by the concatenation of row 1 of `mat` with row 1 of `mat`, and so on. These indices are produced as follows

```
> ind <- expand.grid(r1 = 1:3, r2 = 1:3)
> ind
  r1 r2
1  1  1
2  2  1
3  3  1
4  1  2
5  2  2
6  3  2
7  1  3
8  2  3
9  3  3
```

Note that to get what your output shows we need to take columns `r2` then `r1` rather than the other way round.

Now I just index `mat` with the second column of `ind` and the first column of `ind` and supply that to `paste0()` the output from which is a vector so we need to reshape it to a matrix.

```
> matrix(paste0(mat[ind[,2], ], mat[ind[,1], ]), ncol = 3)
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,] "AA" "BB" "AA"
 [2,] "AA" "BA" "AB"
 [3,] "AB" "BA" "AA"
 [4,] "AA" "AB" "BA"
 [5,] "AA" "AA" "BB"
 [6,] "AB" "AA" "BA"
 [7,] "BA" "AB" "AA"
 [8,] "BA" "AA" "AB"
 [9,] "BB" "AA" "AA"
```

The `paste0()` step returns a vector of the pasted strings:

```
> paste0(mat[ind[,2], ], mat[ind[,1], ])
 [1] "AA" "AA" "AB" "AA" "AA" "AB" "BA" "BA" "BB" "BB" "BA" "BA" "AB" "AA" "AA"
[16] "AB" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AB" "AA" "BA" "BB" "BA" "AA" "AB" "AA"
```

The trick as to why the matrix restructuring shown above works is to note that the entries in the output from `paste0()` are in column-major order because of how the index `ind` was formed. Essentially the two arguments passed to `paste0()` are:

```
> mat[ind[,2], ]
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,] "A"  "B"  "A" 
 [2,] "A"  "B"  "A" 
 [3,] "A"  "B"  "A" 
 [4,] "A"  "A"  "B" 
 [5,] "A"  "A"  "B" 
 [6,] "A"  "A"  "B" 
 [7,] "B"  "A"  "A" 
 [8,] "B"  "A"  "A" 
 [9,] "B"  "A"  "A" 
> mat[ind[,1], ]
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,] "A"  "B"  "A" 
 [2,] "A"  "A"  "B" 
 [3,] "B"  "A"  "A" 
 [4,] "A"  "B"  "A" 
 [5,] "A"  "A"  "B" 
 [6,] "B"  "A"  "A" 
 [7,] "A"  "B"  "A" 
 [8,] "A"  "A"  "B" 
 [9,] "B"  "A"  "A"
```

R treats each as a vector and hence the output is a vector, but because R stores matrices by columns, we fill our output matrix with the pasted strings by columns also.

Answer (score 1):

You might not need a couple of loops to get your output, here is a suggestion:

To start with, let's generate your sample matrix:

```
M <- matrix(c("A","B","A","A","A","B","B","A","A"), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
rownames(M) <- c("Line1","Line2","Line3")
colnames(M) <- c("M1","M2","M3")
```

An easy to generate all possible pairs between items in a vector is to use `expand.grid()`:

```
d <- expand.grid(rownames(M), rownames(M))
```

Generates the columns X and Y in your desired output:

```
   Var1  Var2
1 Line1 Line1
2 Line2 Line1
3 Line3 Line1
4 Line1 Line2
5 Line2 Line2
6 Line3 Line2
7 Line1 Line3
8 Line2 Line3
9 Line3 Line3
```

Then, what you could do is to `apply()` a function to each row that pastes together the corresponding M1,M2,M3 values:

```
apply(d, 1, function(x) { paste(M[x[1],], paste(M[x[2],]), sep="")} )
```

It will generate the right combinations, but not with the right format (yet):

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,] "AA" "AA" "BA" "AA" "AA" "BA" "AB" "AB" "BB"
[2,] "BB" "AB" "AB" "BA" "AA" "AA" "BA" "AA" "AA"
[3,] "AA" "BA" "AA" "AB" "BB" "AB" "AA" "BA" "AA"
```

To flip the matrix in the right direction, you simply have to transpose it.

From there, you can wrap everything into a data frame, in one go:

```
df <- data.frame( d, t(apply(d, 1, function(x) { paste(M[x[1],], paste(M[x[2],]), sep="")} ))
colnames(df) <- c("X","Y","M1","M2", "M3")
```

and here it is.

To be more efficient, you can finally write a little function to which you submit any M matrix.

```
get.it <- function(M){ 
    d <- expand.grid(rownames(M), rownames(M))
    e <- t(apply(d, 1, function(x) { paste(M[x[1],], paste(M[x[2],]), sep="")} ))
    output<- data.frame( d, e)
    colnames(output) <- c("X","Y","M1","M2","M3")
return(output)
}
```

and `get.it(M)` should work!

Comment: note that the colnames would become a problem if you have more than 3 columns, but the principle should be otherwise the same with any column / item set (e.g. A, B, C, D...).

Comment: Wow, you both are amazing. I would never have been able to find such efficient approaches myself. Both of them work like a charm. I am going to use them to reconstruct the full diallel for 70x400. Thanks a lot for your help! Ronny